# How to use sstableloader?

Tags: cassandra, streaming

i use Cassandra 3.4 on some centos 7 machines.

I have 2 clusters:

Cluster 1 with 2 DC , DC1 has 2 machines 192.168.0.171/192.168.172, DC2 has 1 machine 192.168.0.173. Cluster 1 has some data on it, on one keyspace with  replication 2 : 1.

Cluster 2 with 1 datacenter , DC3 has 2 machines. 192.168.0.174/192.168.0.175.

On second cluster, DC3, I create the keyspace : "keyspace1" with NetworkTopologyStrategy : DC3 : 2.

Streamed some cassandra-stress on 192.168.0.175 :

cassandra-stress write n=1000000 -node 192.168.0.175.

In this moment cassandra-stress should generate some garbage data.

Checked the /var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace1/standard1-97a771600d4011e69a5a13282caaa658 and there i have some ma-1-big-Data.db 57 Mb, ma-2-big-Data.db 65 Mb, ma-3-big-Data.db 65 Mb.

My question :

Let`s assume the garbage data is actual data and i want to stream from Cluster 2 this data into Cluster 1.
How can i do that by using sstableloader?

NOTE: Please give, if possible, example with commands ( i`m quite newbie in domain :( )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bin/sstableloader -d 192.168.0.171,192.168.172 /var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace1/standard1-97a771600d4011e69a5a13282caaa658

this command will load data from one cluster to another cluster

Note: keyspace and table should exist in both clusters, and the tables should have the same schema.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong : I need to have the same keyspace and the same tables from the keyspace created onto the cluster i want to move my data in!?

Comment: Succeded to move data in the end, but only after i created on the target cluster the keyspace and the table in same format as they were on the original cluster.

Comment: You command just streams data on one node of the original cluster to the target cluster? And we need to run sstableloader on all nodes of the origin cluster?